# MySQL: What is the most performant way of storing a whole year (365 elements) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Within a project, I have to store the daily availability of different meeting rooms. So let's suppose around 1.000.000 meeting rooms, where each meeting room is in a city, and a city could have hundreds of meeting rooms.

I would also like to be able to make SELECT Queries entering the city and the availability that I need, so I would like to get a list of the available meeting rooms for a day, or set of continues days, in a concrete city.

I have one table called "MeetingRoom", when I store the city and the name of the meeting room, but my design question is how to design the availability part:

- Is it better in terms of performance to have a binary array that stores the 365 days of the year with a '1' or '0' according to the availability of the meeting room?
- Is it better in terms of performance to have another table called "Availability" that stores a DATE and a BIT with the availability, and then JOIN both tables for each meeting room that exists in a city?
- Could it better another option I don't have in mind?

I wonder what querying time would be optimal having around 1.000.000 meeting rooms, and searching for the meeting rooms in a city and available for concrete days. Is it crazy about thinking in database responses below 100 ms?

Some colleagues told me that I should also consider to migrate to MongoDB or NoSQL approach. I don't know if a change of DB could fit better with my issues, or if it don't. Any comment about this?

Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: Why not do the `Availability` table, but just not include rows for when the room is not available? The table could be as simple as just a unique ID for the room, and a date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but if it doesn't, please write me to delete the answer.

Instead of these options you may want to consider that in the "Availability" table to store only the id(surrogate) of the room and the date on which it is reserved. So when you select the data and join both tables you will get only the reserved rooms. I personally think that there is no point of storing all of the room-date relations with status.

Moreover, to improve the performance you can create non-clustered index on the City column for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very useful! I will also try the non-clustered index for the city, it can work very good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please don't fill your database with lots of rows which are default values.

so you don't store availability of a meeting room, you store booking of a meeting room.

primary key of booking table is date and room id , other fields are who booked this room, when booking was asked, a booking id...

If it is possible to book meeting room for part of the day then primary key should be start_date and room id, end date is stored in another field of the table.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds very good, and I think it is a very good approach!
I will try it and check the results

Comment: Laurent, one more question. How can I create the select query for MySQL in order to be sure that all the days between two dates, the meeting room is not booked? Thanks!

Comment: If this query returns NB>0 then room is not available on one of  the dates specified : select count(1) as NB from booking where roomid=MyRoomId and booking_date between MyStartDate and MyEndDate; IF NB=0 then room is available